# Authentication with SQLite

Tags: php, sqlite, security

I'm new to SQLite and something shocks me. There is no authentication -> no security. You just have to open the file with `sqlite_open()`.

So, I wonder, if I have a website like **www.mywebsite.com** with basic `index.html` and a directory `SQLITE` with the file `bdd.sqlite` in it, what will stop "bad" people to open my `bdd.sqlite` file if they know where it is? I suppose they can do: `sqlite_open(www.mywebsite.com/SQLITE/bdd.sqlite)`?

Is there a way to add authentication with SQLite? (I know, it may be stupid because it's agains the goal of sqlite).

PS: if you have some good documentation about SQLite (using PHP 5.3), please give me in comment.

Comment: you're right, is there something i shoud do to link it? Or destroy this?

Comment: @ssbb Just leave it and flag as a duplicate. There is already an answer so you cannot remove it.

Comment: "I'm new to SQLite and something shocks me. There is no authentication -> no security" - MySQL is almost as bad when it accepts any username.

Answer (score 1):

Sqlite security can be provided with different approaches based on the platform, You can find good information about sqlite web security on [this site](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=SqliteWebSecurity). Besides it, [SQLCipher](http://sqlcipher.net/) is the encrypts the whole database and if any one get the database from the iOS device still it will prompt for a password otherwise is will not allow user to see the same.
In addition, in android you can use `System.Data.Sqlite` wrapper, which includes encryption.

Concisely you should encrypt the data somehow to increase the security of your application related to sqlite part. Although modification in access level when possible (like appache server) may help to reach this aim.